# Ruby-On-Rails how to make boolean gender selection from radio button appear as string(M or F) in show.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean

When creating a new user they select male of female with a radio button.
When I go to the show view their gender is displayed as true or false not as male or female.

```
_form.html.erb
  <%= f.label :gender %><br />
 <%= f.label :gender, "Male", :value => "true"  %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, true %>
<%= f.label :gender, "Female", :value => "false" %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, false %>


Show.html.erb
<p>
  <strong>Gender:</strong>
  <%= @user.gender %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use a boolean to represent gender.

There are quite a few countries in the world (Australia, Germany etc) that allow you to legally have other genders than female or male. I don't want to digress into a political discussion but using booleans for anything that is not truly a boolean condition is not a good idea.

If you want a final argument why you should not use a boolean consider this:

```
User.find(1).gender?
```

What is the return value of this expression?

Instead use an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). Which means you should use an integer column in the database.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum gender: [:undisclosed, :female, :male, :other]
end
```

This will let you do:

```
user.male?
User.female # User.where(gender: :female)
user.female! # Makes a user female.
```

To create radio buttons you would use:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "male") %>
<%= label_tag(:gender_male,   "Male") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "female") %>
<%= label_tag(:gender_female, "Female") %>
```

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying, this is just a uni assignment. If it was a real web application I was making of course I wouldn't make gender a boolean but i've already done that and I don't want to delete my scaffold and have to re-do lots of work.

Comment: Changing one column is hardly a lot of work. You don't have scaffold from scratch - just create a migration to change the table.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise that. How do I do that?

Comment: If that does help please ask a new question